# Cannot use hyperlink when protecting sheets without allowing user to select locked cells

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a worksheet that has a bunch of dynamic hyperlinks that change based on a drop down menu.  Only the cells with drop down menus are unlocked.  I have "select locked cells" unchecked so that when I protect the sheet, users can only select the drop down menus.  Unfortunately, when I do this, the hyperlinks are no longer usable.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

**UPDATE***

as requested,  the code for my dynamic hyperlink cells:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B4,'Data Sheet'!A2:A103,0)),"",HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(B4,'Data Sheet'!A:S,7,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B4,'Data Sheet'!A:S,5,FALSE)&" - "&VLOOKUP(B4,'Data Sheet'!A:S,6,FALSE)))
```

1) Cell B4 is the drop down where the user selects a particular option.  The hyperlinks change based on this selection.

2) 'data sheet' is a separate sheet that houses all of the reference data in an array.

this basically says:  does the value in B4 match the first column in my data chart?  if so, use a hyperlink formula using VLOOKUP to insert the corresponding URL into the formula.

Comment: How are you generating the hyperlinks? I think in the end you have to consider that anything that the user interacts with has to be unlocked. So now we move into mitigating the dangers of the user changing where the hyperlink is located. If your generating through `HYPERLINK` formula than it would be a concern that users might change your formula. If you generate it through VBA... doesn't seem much a concern as it is generated dynamically every time the dropdowns change without the user having opportunity to change the script.

Comment: I use VLOOKUP within a =hyperlink formula to make the hyperlink dynamic.  Preventing users from altering the formula is not the issue.  The cells containing the hyperlink are locked.  I would just like to uncheck the box that makes locked cells selectable.  Mostly for aesthetic reasons.  It just looks more professional in my opinion.  I will ask on super users if you think this is more appropriate for that forum. Thanks!

Comment: Are you willing to use VBA?

Comment: @EEM Sure, if that is the only way to make the hyperlink trigger, that would be a valid answer. At least for the bounty, dunno about the OPs requirements.

Comment: Trying to asses what else is involved in the issue, so got some questions:  1) How many hyperlinks cells do you have? 2) Are those Hyperlinks pointing to places in the same workbook? 3) Are those places unprotected? 4) when you said "Preventing users from altering the formula is not the issue." it's because: "The cells containing the hyperlink are locked."? 5) Would you share the `VLOOKUP` formula for the Hyperlink?

Comment: 1) anywhere from 0 to 14 depending on the selection in a drop down menu. There are 14 cells that will either have a hyperlink or be blank.  2). All hyperlinks go to web pages. 3) n/a. 4). Exactly. The cells with hyperlinks are locked.  5). Yes,  gladly.  will post shortly, although I don't think it will have any bearing on the solution.  It's just a formula that changes the hyperlink location.

Comment: @Jamiho Would you please post the formula

Comment: Could you just unlock the cells containing the hyperlink formula (similar to how you unlocked the dropdowns)? They would be selectable, but no others, and it should work. I know you said this was for aesthetic reasons, but if you did become concerned about someone changing the formula, you could write a VBA solution that on the cell change, it writes the same formula back to the cell with all the vlookups. You can also hide the formula without protecting it, if you wish, with the cell options.

Answer (score 6):

*This is my understanding of the settings and requirements:*

**Settings**

- There is a protected worksheet with a dropdown menu which updates other cells containing VLOOKUP\HYPERLINK formulas.
- All cells in the worksheet, excluding the dropdown menus, are protected.
- The value of the cells containing VLOOKUP\HYPERLINK formulas, could equal to a www address or blank depending on the value of the dropdown menu. As such, all hyperlinks point to web pages or are blank.
- The worksheet `EnableSelection` is set to `xlUnlockedCells` which determines that once the worksheet is protected “Only unlocked cells can be selected.”

**Requirements**
 - Need to maintain the worksheet protected to safeguard al the contents including the VLOOKUP\HYPERLINK formulas.

- Need to allow users to select\activate only unprotected cells mostly for aesthetic reasons and to deliver a professional product.

*This solution uses the following resources*

- The `HYPERLINK` function
- An `UDF` (user defined function)
- Two `Public Variables` and
- The `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event

> *When an `UDF` is wrapped into a `HYPERLINK` function it causes that*
>   *every time the mouse hovers over the cell containing the combined*
>   *formula of `HYPERLINK(UDF,[FriendlyName])` the `UDF` is triggered.*

We’ll use a `Public Variable` to hold the `LinkLocation`, to be used later to follow the hyperlink upon users decision.

And a second `Public Variable` to set the time when the `LinkLocation` was last updated.

We’ll mimic the manner in which the hyperlink is “normally” activated:

- by which an user selects a cell and clicks the hyperlink in the selected cell.
- Instead the user hovers over the cell with the hyperlink *(the UDF feeds the `LinkLocation` and the time into the public variables)* and `DoubleClicks` the cell *(triggering the worksheet event to follow the hyperlink, validating first the time when the `LinkLocation` was last updated to ensure it stills actual and clearing the `LinkLocation` variable)*.

First we need to ensure that the formulas used in the worksheet to generate the Dynamic Hyperlinks have the appropriated structure:

Assuming the current VLOOKUP\HYPERLINK formulas have the following structure:
*(have to work based on assumptions as the actual formula was not provided)*

```
=IFERROR( HYPERLINK( VLOOKUP( DropDownCell , Range , Column, False ), FriendlyName ), "" )
```

We need to change that formula to the following structure:

```
=IFERROR( HYPERLINK( UDF( VLOOKUP( DropDownCell , Range , Column, False ) ), FriendlyName ), "" )
```

The following procedures take care of modifying the formulas structure to make them suitable for the solution proposed. *Suggest to copy both in a separated module named “Maintenance”.*

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Wsh_FmlHyperlinks_Reset()
Const kWshPss As String = "WshPssWrd"
Const kHypLnk As String = "HYPERLINK("
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet, rHyplnk As Range
Dim rCll As Range, sHypLnkFml As String
Dim sOld As String, sNew As String

    Rem Application Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Rem Set & Unprotect Worksheet
    Set WshTrg = ActiveSheet
    WshTrg.Unprotect kWshPss

    Rem Find Hyperlink Formulas
    If Not (Rng_Find_Set(WshTrg.UsedRange, _
        rHyplnk, kHypLnk, xlFormulas, xlPart)) Then Exit Sub
    If rHyplnk Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Rem Add Hyperlinks Names
    For Each rCll In rHyplnk.Cells
        With rCll
            sHypLnkFml = .Formula
            sOld = "HYPERLINK( VLOOKUP("
            sNew = "HYPERLINK( Udf_HypLnkLct_Set( VLOOKUP("
                sHypLnkFml = Replace(sHypLnkFml, sOld, sNew)
            sOld = ", FALSE ),"
            sNew = ", FALSE ) ),"
                sHypLnkFml = Replace(sHypLnkFml, sOld, sNew)
            .Formula = sHypLnkFml
    End With: Next

    Rem Protect Worksheet
    WshTrg.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    WshTrg.Protect Password:=kWshPss

    Rem Application Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Function Rng_Find_Set(rInp As Range, rOut As Range, _
    vWhat As Variant, eLookIn As XlFindLookIn, eLookAt As XlLookAt) As Boolean
Dim rFound As Range, sFound1st As String
    With rInp
        Set rFound = .Find( _
            What:=vWhat, After:=.Cells(1), _
            LookIn:=eLookIn, LookAt:=eLookAt, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not (rFound Is Nothing) Then
            sFound1st = rFound.Address
            Do
                If rOut Is Nothing Then
                    Set rOut = rFound
                Else
                    Set rOut = Union(rOut, rFound)
                End If
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFound1st
    End If:  End With
    Rem Set Results
    If Not (rOut Is Nothing) Then Rng_Find_Set = True
End Function
```

These are the Public Variables and the UDF. *Suggest to copy them in a separated Module.*

```
Option Explicit

Public psHypLnkLoct As String, pdTmeNow As Date

Public Function Udf_HypLnkLct_Set(sHypLnkFml As String) As String
    psHypLnkLoct = sHypLnkFml
    pdTmeNow = Now
End Function
```

And *copy this procedure in the Module of the protected worksheet* with the dynamically generated hyperlinks.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Now = pdTmeNow And psHypLnkLoct <> Empty Then
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=psHypLnkLoct, NewWindow:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Elegant solution! Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this have a few issues? 1) You need to cancel the double click as Excel will automatically enter the next available unlocked cell if you double click on a locked cell. If OPs sheet contains even one unlocked cell, this could cause issues. 2) Won't this only fire if the user hovers the cell and immediately double clicks? If the user hovers the cell and waits a few seconds, won't the pdTimeNow variable be redundant? I could be wrong, I'm not at Excel at the minute so I can't run it and check

Comment: @AranDG Cancelling the doubleclick-event by setting the cancel-variable to `True` should be trivial, if it causes trouble. That said, I am also curious about the `pdTimeNow` variable and its purpose.

Comment: @AranDG 1) No need to cancel the double click, doing it’s redundant. What double click actually does (i.e. not event activated) is to select the cell where the double click took place, since the cell is protected nothing happens.
2a) I’m surprised about this question, should know how about the Hyperlink\UDF combination behavior used in your post. *The Hyperlink\Udf combination causes that every time the mouse moves over the cell the UDF gets fired.*
2b) pdTimeNow gets updated every time the user moves the mouse over the cell, that includes the Double Click move.

Comment: @eirikdaude The purpose of the pdTimeNow is to manage the life of the psHypLnkLoct variable and provide similar behavior as the standard click of a hyperlink. In a normal environment to activate a Hyperlink the user clicks the cell where the link is located, we don’t expect the hyperlink to get fired if the user selects the cell with hyperlink then moves to another cell and clicks.

Comment: @eirikdaude In the case at hand the psHypLnkLoct gets loaded once the mouse moves over the cell with the hyperlink formula, but the user could be just passing by that cell while moving to another cell or just accidentally passed over it, nevertheless this move triggers the UDF, this is unnoticed as the UDF is not intrusive (opposite behavior can be clearly seen in AranDG post). Therefore, as soon as the double click event is fired it uses the pdTimeNow to validate the last time the psHypLnkLoct was loaded and if it was not loaded `NOW` then the psHypLnkLoct has become obsolete and it’s cleared

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, the two variables are used to prevent a hyperlink in (selected?) cells elsewhere in the worksheet to be triggered, when a doubleclick-event is captured for a given cell. However, can't you just use the `Target`-variable of the event to make sure the hyperlink is from the cell you're doubleclicking? Or is there some shenanigans through which a different cell can be assigned to `Target`?

Comment: @eirikdaude *The `Target` range in all `Worksheets Events` refers to the active `Selection` range*. As you know the worksheet is protected and the worksheet property `EnableSelection` is set to `xlUnlockedCells` so the `Target` range returned by the event when double click over a protected cell is not that protected cell, as it could not be selected.

Comment: You are indeed correct - the method described above worked for me in a worksheet where *no* selection was allowed, so I assumed it would be true in other cases too. Shows the dangers of making assumptions, I guess :) Anyway, I awarded the bounty to you a little while ago, as I was worried it was gonna time out. Cool solution!

Comment: I think there is no danger in making assumptions, the real danger is when those assumptions are baseless, speculative, with lack of research. Unfortunately, we have to many answers based on that kind of assumptions in the site.     BTW this look funny though *so I assumed it would be true in other cases too. Shows the dangers of making assumptions*.

Comment: Sorry for my silence..  I am a 32 year old undergrad student with a family, and finals are approaching, so I have been extremely busy.  Your assessment of the settings and requirement are dead on!  I will look through all of this and try to incorporate this VBA into my worksheet and report back shortly.

Comment: I have added my code to my original post.  basically similar to your guess.   I use a VLOOKUP for both the URL and "friendly name".  instead of ISERROR, I use ISNA and MATCH.

Comment: No problem, **Family is a great communion, enjoy it!** Thanks for posting the formula. I have compared with the one I used in the answer and the procedure `Wsh_FmlHyperlinks_Reset` will do the changes needed to your formulas provided that you clear the additional blank spaces included to ease the reading and understanding of the formula structures. Change these lines:   
`sOld = "HYPERLINK( VLOOKUP("`   
`sOld = ", FALSE ),"`   
to these:   
`sOld = "HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP("`   
`sOld = ",FALSE),"`  *Let me know the results and if satisfied accept the answer.*

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use VBA, you could use the following code for the Sheet(s) in question, this will replicate the click event for the hyperlink and try and open in the target's native format

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If InStr(1, Target.Formula, "HYPERLINK", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    On Error Resume Next

    Target.Hyperlinks(1).Follow (True)

    On Error GoTo 0

End If

End Sub
```

**Update**

I think I have a bit of a work around. I've pinched some code from [here](http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html) which allows a roll over action to trigger some vba. So, let's say you have your link in cell A1. Change your link to the following:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(MyMouseOverEvent("http://www.google.com"),"Hover"),"Hover")
```

You can change your link dynamically providing it returns a string. Now create a new module and paste in the following:

```
Public Function MyMouseOverEvent(varLink As String)
    varResponse = MsgBox("Would you like to open link to: '" & varLink & "'?", vbYesNo, "Confirm")
    If varResponse = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=varLink, NewWindow:=True
    End If
End Function
```

The only drawback is that it fires the code on hover instead of on click, however the pop up box will allow the user to decide if they want to follow said link. I'll keep looking at it and see if I can find a work aorund for the click, but I think it's progressing as it will fire even when fully protected. I am using Excel 2010 if that helps.

Comment: Heh, if this works, that is a lot simpler than I expeccted  the answer to be. Will the `SelectionChange`-event trigger if the cell is locked and selection of locked cell isn't allowed though? I can't really test until back at work on Monday, but looks good! :)

Comment: Thanks for reviving my unanswered question.  I'm generally fine incorporating VBA into this and will give the code a try.

Comment: Please accept my apologies, it looks like I stumbled on a bit of a quirk in Excel 2010. If the cell containing the hyperlink is selected during the protection process, the link works using the code above, however once another cell is selected, the code fails. I'll try another method

Comment: @Jamiho was this work around acceptable or do you require the click event?